# A good one-word synonym for "over-spent'

Tags: word-choice

If you throw a party for 100 people and it ends up with only 5 people showing up, it looks like an over-spent party. It shows that the money has been wasted but it's also unintentionally.

Can I also say, it's an(a):

> extravagant party , Lavish party, or squandered party?

Is there an exact *one-word synonym* for over-spent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have a use case for [**prodigal**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prodigal) in its original sense, which was about "wasteful expenditure". It doesn't really convey the wasted effort aspect.

There's [**Overprepared**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overprepared) or [**Overplanned**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overplan) which do convey wasted effort, but not necessarily costs or having anything to do with festivities.

Lastly you have [**profligate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/profligate), which is similar to prodigal, but connoting immorality or hedonism.

Answer (score 1):

When I was growing up (1960s into 1970s), "splurged" was the common one I heard from my parents.

To splurge was to spend money you really shouldn't, especially on "guilty pleasure" items (like a new purse or fancy shoes for Mom or a hunting rifle for Dad -- or a candy bar for me on twenty-five cents a week allowance).

Alternatively, *intentional* conspicuous waste was called "potlatch", based on a Nez Perce language word describing when a wealthy individual would literally destroy expensive items, just to show they weren't important.